# How can I add a class from an array of 4 classes until all classes have been used up?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table on my html page.

I have a `while` loop that runs four times and then gives four random cells a `class` of `weapon` as you can see below. This turns them orange.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  var tblB = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tblB);

  $("td").addClass('empty');




  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tblB.appendChild(tr);
    $(tr).attr('data-x', i)

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      tr.appendChild(td);

      $(td).attr('data-y', j);
    }

  }
  body.appendChild(table);



  var weapons = 0;


  while (weapons < 4) {
    var randomRow = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
    var randomCol = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);

    var randomCellNew = $($("tr[data-x=" + randomRow + "] > td[data-y=" + randomCol + "]"));
    if (randomCellNew.hasClass('empty') === true && randomCellNew.hasClass('dimmed') === false) {
      randomCellNew.addClass('weapon').removeClass('empty');
      weapons++
    }
  }

})
```

```css
table td {
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background-image: url('image.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.weapon {
  background: orange;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.snowballs {
  background-image: url("snowball.png");
  background-size: contain;
  /* <------ */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.gun {
  background-image: url("gun.png");
  background-size: contain;
  /* <------ */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  /* box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px yellow; */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.nunchucks {
  background-image: url("nunchucks.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

.ninjastar {
  background-image: url("ninjastar.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px yellow;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of giving them all the same class I would like to give 4 them individual classes so they contain 4 images, one each.
So the loop would run and then one by one place one of the four images in 4 random cells until all 4 classes are used.

I tried to use `:nth of type` in CSS but it didn't work properly.
Is there another way?
I thought about looping through an array of classes but not sure how to work it out.

How can I solve this issue still using the `if` statment and `randomCellNew variable`?
By the way, all of this happens on load of page not with a click function or any other function.

If the code above doesn't work, I have it on https://jsfiddle.net/johnroiste/y2qktb8z/4/

Comment: var weapons = Array('gun', 'nunchucks', 'snowballs');
var weaponOfChoice = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];

If the weapon only should be used once you can remove it from the array before picking a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing that with an array:

```js
var classes = ['snowballs', 'gun', 'nunchucks', 'ninjastar'];

var weapons = 0;
//////Trying to use a while or for loop to place an additional 4 orange squares on the table using a similar method to the one for obs/dimmed

while (weapons < 4) {
  var randomRow = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);
  var randomCol = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);

  var randomCellNew = $($("tr[data-x=" + randomRow + "] > td[data-y=" + randomCol + "]"));
  if (randomCellNew.hasClass('empty') === true && randomCellNew.hasClass('dimmed') === false) {
    randomCellNew.addClass(classes[weapons]).removeClass('empty');
    weapons++
    // console.log(randomNum + randomCol);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out exactly this:
    randomCellNew.addClass(classes[weapons]).removeClass('empty');
Cheers!

Comment: The only problem I am having with it is some of the <td> are over each other sometimes now, and weapons therefore can be on top of each other or players etc.

Comment: The reason is because the class "highlightPath" is being added after the assignment of classes("snowballs", "gun", etc.) to the elements. You can put a check before adding "highlightPath" to the elements, if they have any of the classes from array "classes"

Comment: Ideally, they should be able to be on the highlightedpath td's without issue

Comment: then what's the issue?